# WTSQueryUserToken return 5 (ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED)

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I have a program runs as SYSTEM and try to query logon user token by the following code:

```
WTSEnumerateSessions(WTS_CURRENT_SERVER_HANDLE, 0, 1, &pSessionInfo, &dwCount);
for (i = 0; i < dwCount; i++) {
    WTS_SESSION_INFO si = pSessionInfo[i];
    if (WTSActive == si.State) {
        WTSQueryUserToken(si.SessionId, &hUserToken)
    }
}
```

The above codes run successfully in Win10. But in Win7 32-bit, WTSQueryUserToken() always return False with error 5 (ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED).

Did I miss any configuration in Win7 environment?

=== Edit ====

My program run as a service which follows the [example](https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-tw/windows/win32/services/installing-a-service).

I expect that my program is run as LocalSystem account as the last second argument (NULL) in CreateServer().

Comment: Did you check if the `SE_TCB_NAME` privilege is enabled on your process? "*To call this function successfully, the calling application must be running within the context of the LocalSystem account and have the SE_TCB_NAME privilege.*"

Comment: Debug it until you find `SetLastError` or one of the related error functions. You should be able to find a more descriptive NTSTATUS code. Probably in the undocumented WinStation stuff.

Comment: if `SE_TCB_NAME` privilege not exist or not enabled error will be another - `ERROR_PRIVILEGE_NOT_HELD`

Comment: i sure that you have `SeTcbPrivilege` but your `TokenUser` not `S-1-5-18` ( `NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM` ) - exactly in this case will be access denied error. need debug process where *lsm.dll* live (it handle this) - you fail in `HRESULT CPrivateRpc::staticRpcSecurityCallback(void *,int)` -> `HRESULT CUtils::IsCallerSystem()` because you not `LocalSystem`

Comment: I just did a test and ensure that this only happens within THREAD. The service create a thread and I add `WTSQueryUserToken()` in both of the service and the thread, it is successful in service but failed in thread.

This only happens Windows 7 32bit. Anyone has experience about this?

Answer (score 1):

The previous version of MSDN documentation for `WTSQueryUserToken` was more complete in terms of possible error values

[image: Error values table]

> **ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED**:
>
> *The caller does not have the appropriate permissions to call this function. The caller must be running within the context of the
> LocalSystem account and have the `SE_TCB_NAME` privilege.*

But when the caller does not have `SE_TCB_NAME` privilege, a different error code is returned:

> **ERROR_PRIVILEGE_NOT_HELD**:
>
> *The caller does not have the `SE_TCB_NAME` privilege.*

So `ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED` is returned when the caller does not run as ***[LocalSystem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/services/localsystem-account)***. Specifically, this means that [`TokenUser`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winnt/ns-winnt-token_user) of the caller's token is not `S-1-5-18` ( *NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM - WellKnownGroup* )

Internally `WTSQueryUserToken` first checks if `SE_TCB_NAME` privilege is held and enabled and if it's not it returns `ERROR_PRIVILEGE_NOT_HELD`.

Otherwise, [`WinStationQueryInformationW`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aa383827(v=vs.85)) is called with [`WinStationUserToken`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-tsts/f333c223-de8a-46e1-a83e-79cbdab92371). The [`WINSTATIONUSERTOKEN`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-tsts/07f9831c-6331-43e5-ba27-d3d58772eb4c) is returned on success. This is remote call to ***LSM*** service, it usually runs in the *svchost.exe* process with *LSM* in its command line. A call is handled by *lsm.dll*, where

```
RPC_STATUS CALLBACK CPrivateRpc::staticRpcSecurityCallback(void *,int);
```

is called (this function is inside *lsm.dll*). Inside it, a function

```
HRESULT CUtils::IsCallerSystem();
```

is called. This function checks that [`TokenUser`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winnt/ne-winnt-token_information_class) of the caller's token is `S-1-5-18` and if not - `CPrivateRpc::staticRpcSecurityCallback` drops the call with `ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED` - and error  returned for caller.

So check in which context your code really runs.

Comment: I run my program as a service by following https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-tw/windows/win32/services/installing-a-service. I expect it is run within LocalSystem account.

Comment: @VincentHuang are you check token at call time ? And you can debug and view where exactly was error

Comment: I used 'GetUserNameA()' to ensure the caller process user is 'SYSTEM'. Did I miss something?

Comment: @VincentHuang use debugger and look where exatly you fail.

Comment: @RbMn Thanks. I am new to Win32 programming. I use debug view but it only captures my own printed log. How can I investigate more deep in Win32 API.

Comment: @VincentHuang without debugging i not view any way research problem.

Comment: After debuging, the phenomenon is every time after the process call FilterConnectCommunicationPort(), it will be always failed to call WTSQueryUserToekn(). Before FilterConnectCommunicationPort(), WTSQueryUserToekn() is called successfully.

Comment: @VincentHuang- i already say - you need query thread token (if exist) just before call `WTSQueryUserToekn`

Comment: Sounds like after calling `FilterConnectCommunicationPort`, the thread token will be changed to another one which is with less privilege to call `WTSQueryUserToekn`??

Comment: @VincentHuang simply check this

Comment: Use `GetCurrentThreadToken` before and after `FilterConnectCommunicationPort`. Got the same value.

Comment: Really don't very clearly understand your sentence. If you have precise function name. It will be helpful.

Comment: @VincentHuang - are you look for `GetCurrentThreadToken` implementation ? if you look for it - you are understand why it always return the same value. also you say that your problem on win7 but this pseudo handle not have sense for win7. you need OpenThreadToken and and query it properties. but more easy use some tool which can show thread/process tokens